# React Testing library - simulate iFrame onLoad

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that renders iFrame inside of it.
I want to test iFrame's `onLoad` functionality but it doesn't triggers simply with the testing library's `render` function. Can I programmatically simulate iFrame's onLoad event with testing library.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck on this one and used:

```
it('should call the onLoad event'), async () => {
  const {container} = render(<MyComponent />)
  fireEvent.load(container.querySelector('iframe')
await waitFor(() => expect(yourOnLoadEvent).toHaveBeenCalled()

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.
I stumbled upon this question and decided to share my working code.
I tried to use `container.querySelector('iframe')`, but it seems like it can't find the iframe, so I took the approach of using `testid`

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        data-testid="google-iframe"
        src="google.com"
        title="google"
        onLoad={() => setIsLoaded(true)}
      />
      {isLoaded && <span>OnLoad Triggered!</span>}
    </div>
  );
};

function renderComponent() {
  render(<MyComponent />);
}

test('Should show the OnLoad message once the iframe has loaded', async () => {
  renderComponent();

  fireEvent.load(screen.getByTestId('google-iframe')!);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText('OnLoad Triggered!')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```